# How to create a view that appears only once?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to create a view ("splash-screen") that presents my application. I want this view to be displayed only once (first use) when starting the application. And for other start I want the application to start directly on my tabview.

thanks,

Comment: What that view represent. Are you taking information from that view and persist that information?

Comment: what you have tried ? what were the issues ? anything will help us to find a solution.

Comment: you can do that by setting a flag in `NSUserDefault`, something like `notAFirstLaunch` BOOL value. Check in `AppDelegate` if `notAFirstLaunch` is `YES` or `NO`. If `NO` than show your one time view else redirect to your table view. When showing `one time view`, store `notAFirstLaunch` to `YES` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: "I would like to create a view" but he means a "splash-screen", in more common parlance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like following way..!

**Objective C**

In your AppDelegate:

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

BOOL isFirstLaunch = [standardUserDefaults boolForKey:@"ThisisFirstLaunch"];

if (!isFirstLaunch) {
    [self presentViewController:YOUR_FIRST_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:YOUR_REGULAR_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
}
```

Save the user response on your first controller:

```
[standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"ThisisFirstLaunch"];
```

**Swift**

In your App Delegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication) {
    if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isFirstLaunch") {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
    }
}
```

In your root view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isFirstLaunch") {
        // FirstLaunch, proceed as normal
    } else {
        // if not
    }
}
```

Then make BOOL to true:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
```